# Relational Model represent relationship with total disjoint entity

Tags: database, database-design, schema, relational-database, entity-relationship

I'm having trouble translating the relationship *"X"* into a relational model before I translate into SQL. This is an example of the problem I'm facing and what I have so far is:

```
Relation: X(1,2)  
Key:2  
IND:X[1]⊆A[1] 

    X[2]⊆C[2]
    X[2]⊆D[2]
    X[2]⊆E[2]

    C[2]⊆X[2]
    D[2]⊆X[2]
    E[2]⊆X[2]
```

The main problem I'm having is how to represent the total disjoint subclasses via IND(inclusion dependencies), because from my in a total disjoint subclass/super class relationship, each subclass can have its own relation, but the super class does not get its own relation. Thanks

[image: Sample ER Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can represent disjoint subtypes in SQL

```
CREATE TABLE Products
 (SKU INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  ProductType CHAR(1) NOT NULL
  CHECK (ProductType IN ('B','C','D')),
  Title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (SKU,ProductType));

CREATE TABLE Books
 (SKU INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  ProductType CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'B' NOT NULL, CHECK (ProductType ='B'),
  Pages SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (SKU,ProductType)
  REFERENCES Products (SKU,ProductType));

CREATE TABLE CDs
 (SKU INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  ProductType CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'C' NOT NULL, CHECK (ProductType ='C'),
  Tracks SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (SKU,ProductType)
  REFERENCES Products (SKU,ProductType));

CREATE TABLE DVDs
 (SKU INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  ProductType CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'D' NOT NULL, CHECK (ProductType ='D'),
  Duration SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (SKU,ProductType)
  REFERENCES Products (SKU,ProductType));
```

Comment: It deserves to be pointed out in addition that, as this solution shows, it should not be assumed too lightly that, by definition, "the super class does not get its own relation".